# How to destructure keys out of an array (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

We just made this code based on a hunch, and it worked. I'm pretty sure it's acceptable. I just want to make sure:

```js
const state = { inProgress: true }
const actions = 'COMPLETE_RICE'
const change = { inProgress: false, rice: 'cooked' }

// Is this destructuring OK?
const {
  0: newState,
  1: newActions,
  2: newChange,
} = [state, actions, change]

console.log('New State:', newState)
console.log('New Actions:', newActions)
console.log('New Change:', newChange)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Any concerns or violations?

I can't find any examples of this and only tried it because I recalled that:

`['one', 'two', 'three']` can be expressed as an object:

```
{
  0: 'one',
  1: 'two',
  2: 'three'
}
```

It's not exactly listed here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

But, it works.

Comment: It works indeed but the end result will not inherit the Array prototype functions so why not destructuring with a simple array ? `const [newState, newActions, newChange] = [state, actions, change]`

Comment: You can use object to extract vars like this. Result will be the same as using `const [newState, newActions, newChange] = [state, actions, change]` but using object like you are doing is just not too nice. It will work but why doing it weird way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an array for a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). There you need no indices, because the array gives the order.

```js
const state = { inProgress: true }
const actions = 'COMPLETE_RICE'
const change = { inProgress: false, rice: 'cooked' }

// Is this destructuring OK?
const [newState, newActions, newChange] = [state, actions, change];

console.log('New State:', newState)
console.log('New Actions:', newActions)
console.log('New Change:', newChange)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of destructuring an array as an object, use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring):

```js
const state = { inProgress: true }
const actions = 'COMPLETE_RICE'
const change = { inProgress: false, rice: 'cooked' }

const [newState, newActions, newChange] = [state, actions, change]

console.log('New State:', newState)
console.log('New Actions:', newActions)
console.log('New Change:', newChange)
```